# How can I get the React-Router to load the same page when the request comes from outside the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a navigation component at the top of the page, and the individual "pages" of my app load below this navbar. There is a search component that can open the view "page" when an item is selected, but if the view page is already open, the navigation caused by the search isn't performed.  Because this navbar (with the search component) is always on the screen (and works from every other page) I am not looking for a solution to "reload the page", since that would be meaningless on any other page.  I want to know how to tell the router that it needs to load this page, regardless of whether it is currently loaded.

Comment: can you give an example and explain what exactly you are having issue with. I am afraid but the description of the question is not very clear.

Comment: You can pass a 'key' parameter to make every path unique.
<Route
  exact
  path="/licenses/:type?"
  render={props => <Licenses key={props.location.pathname} {...props} /> }
/>

Comment: @CodeOfLife I've described exactly what I'm having trouble with.  Can you tell me what isn't clear so I can try to explain it better?

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach but if the view page is already open, the navigation caused by the search isn't performed. Because this navbar (with the search component) is always on the screen (and works from every other page).
Basically what exactly is happening in view page.

Comment: @CodeOfLife The navbar allows me to change pages.  It *also* has a component (search) that will load one specific page -- the view page.  When I navigate to any other page, then use the search, it loads the view page (which shows me the contents of the record I have searched for).  If the view page is already up (because I navigated to it directly or by a previous search), it does not load the view page, nor load the contents of the record I have searched for.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. let me post my answer and then we can see whether it can work or not.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposed solution.
So, whenever you navigate to a page(which i presume is a component) the path in the broswer would change so that you can render your component, Something like this

```
export function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />

          <Route exact path="/orders" component={Orders} />
          <Route exact path="/products/:id" component={View} />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
```

So in the View component I would suggest you to check for the path name (basically something like a state change) whenever you are searching for the product.
So assume you navigate to a new page(so your path will change),so you can have this as a state in your view component and initiaize your View component as new search.
Here is some pseudo code

```
export function View(props){
const[Initial,setInitial]=useState();
setInitial(props.pathName)
//do some logic if the state changes;
}
```

This is what I would try to do.

Now,how do i pass the pathname to the View component ??
For that create a route which should take pathname as a parameter and then that parameter can be a prop to view component.something like this (not an exact code)

```
<ViewRoute path={this.state.path}  component={View} />
```